# How to retrieve eth0 id programmatically

Tags: c++, c, unix, ipv6

When I gave 
`/sbin/ip addr show` in my Linux machine. I got output like below

```
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:21:02:16:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff .. so on
```

how to retrieve the above id 3 for `eth0` programmatically in C or CPP.

Comment: You can use `popen` command and store it's result.

Comment: why do you need the `3` ? It's usually better to refer to the interface by name (`eth0`)

Comment: The source code of `ip addr` seems to be here: https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/ip/ipaddress.c

Comment: Why he has been downvoted so much? It looks like a normal question

Comment: I agree with @AndreHolzner, why do you want the numeric id number? AFAIK, that number is useless to you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [if_nametoindex](http://linux.die.net/man/3/if_nametoindex)() function.

```
unsigned int idx = if_nametoindex("eth0");
if (idx == 0) {
    perror("if_nametoindex");
 }
```

Comment: In real code you should actually handle ENXIO a bit more intelligently :)

Answer (score 2):

The standard linux c library for handling network interfaces is **[getifaddrs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html)**.

You can get a linked list of the existing interfaces from getifaddrs and count them till you find the one you're looking for.

Other than that it is not completely clear **why** you need that number (I am getting the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) hunch). I'm saying that because the OS differs the interfaces by name.